# sort a pair vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,j;
vector< pair<int,int> > v;

    v.push_back(make_pair(4,2));
    v.push_back(make_pair(1,3));
    v.push_back(make_pair(5,4));

sort(v.begin(), v.end());

for(i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    cout<<v[i].first<<" "<<v[i].second<<endl;
}
```

**The output to the above code is---**

```
1 3 
4 2
5 4
```

We can see from the **output** that **sort function** has sorted v[i].first but what if we only want to sort v[i].second or if we want to sort both of them,how to then accomplish the task?

Comment: use a `std::map`, a possibly a custom comparer (a lambda will do it)

Comment: sorry but i have never implemented a map , i don't know anything about it

Comment: Can you clarify what results you are looking for? "if we want to sort both"; Do you want the output to be `1 2` `4 3` `5 4`?

Comment: @quantdev Whether he uses `sort` or a `map` is immaterial -- he'll need a custom comparator either way.

Comment: Ok. Sorting both `first` and `second` independently is not supported. You could put them in different vectors and sort each vector independently.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Yes it is. You use a custom comparator.

Comment: It already "sorts both of them". It does a "lexical comparison", which means it compares `a.first` to `b.first`, then if (and only if) they're equal, compares `a.second` to `b.second`.

Comment: @NeilKirk The key word you are missing is "independently". OP seems to want to sort the list of `x.first` independently of the list of `x.second`, such that the resulting vector is *not* a permutation of the original pairs. This is what I was getting at in my earlier comment with the example output.

Comment: @MagnusHoff He wants to sort by second independently of first, but keep both values in the resulting vector together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify your custom comparer. In C++14 it can be done very concisely:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y){return x.second < y.second;});
```

Comment: Note that the syntax there requires a C++11 compiler at least. If your compiler is older, use an explicit functor class (as in ravi's answer) or a free function (as in Mr. kbok's).

Comment: @Sneftel not even C++11, C++14 :)

Comment: @AntonSavin should it not be `const auto &x, const auto &y` for most purposes? Also, is there a compiler that can actually deduce the types in that context?

Comment: @PeterT thanks for pointing out, actually `auto&&` is more correct.

Comment: @PeterT latest clang and GCC can do it with -std=c++1y flag.

Comment: what does auto mean and what this "[ ]" symbolizes ,can u please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @SurayansTiwari it's a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). On a first approximation you can think of it as an anonymous function which accepts template parameters `x` and `y` (which is specified by using `auto`).

Comment: @AntonSavin you said to PeterT "actually `auto&&` is more correct" - why?  There's no question of copying/moving the objects, so a `const &` seems not only 100% adequate and appropriate but also available now with C++11... am I missing something?

Comment: @TonyD `auto &&` can bind both lvalue and rvalue references (equivalent to T&& in templates), so if you, for whatever reason pass it an rvalue reference and you forward it inside the comparator, then `auto &&` would be more efficient. Not that it matters for any comparators I know, but for templates in general it sometimes does matter.

Comment: I do however not know whether `auto &&` can bind a `const T&`

Comment: @PeterT [It can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/493a2fb5d4e0a432). Also you may search for occurences of `auto&&` in the text of C++ standard. Also you may read [this excellent article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: @PeterT OK I was wrong about "more correct". I thought `const auto&` wouldn't work for `vector<bool>` but it actually works. And `auto&&` binds as non-const reference if it can, thus allowing modifications, so `const auto&` is better.

Comment: @TonyD regardless of `auto&&` or `const auto&` it's a C++14 feature (called generic lambda)

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function accepts a *comparison function object* as a parameter:

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare> void sort(
    RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp);
```

A working comparison function for the `second` member of `pair` would be:

```
bool cmp(const std::pair<int,int>& a, const std::pair<int,int>& b) {
    return a.second < b.second;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default it would sort on the basis of first element much as your program is doing. However you could pass third argument to sort as your-defined comparator to do what-ever you want to do...

You can have your own comparator for sorting on right element:-

```
struct sort_second {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int,int> &left, const std::pair<int,int> &right) {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sort_second());
```

Comment: `operator()` should be `const`.

Comment: Alternatively it does not need to be a class, it can just be a function.